# Dynamic Type Text get clipped

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, dynamic-text

I'm implementing dynamic types in my iOS 10 app using custom fonts. However, when using the largest text setting, the `UILabel` gets clipped - (I don't know the exact term to describe this. If you know, please correct me) - please see screenshot below:

[image]

the `UILabel` for "Date" below has the same settings for the `UILabel` "name" so I wonder why it has a different behavior. I want the text to not be clipped.

EDIT:
here is a screenshot of the `UILabel` properties

[image]

Comment: Looks like the label's height isn't being adjusted for the larger font. How is your label setup? Show relevant code or a screenshot of the relevant settings in your storyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy i added a screenshot of the `UILabel` properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use minimumScaleFactor programmatically

yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;

yourLabel.minimumScaleFactor=0.5;

This will take care of your font size according width of label and text.

Comment: You should post a link to the answer you copied, not just a link to the question with the answer you copied.

Comment: Click on Fixed font size and then choose Minimum font size and set the value to actual value /2.